# How to convert "mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM AM" to 2018-03-05T08:27:49.338Z in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to convert "03/07/2018 10:00 AM" string to UTC format ,
i tried below code but it isn't working

```js
    var dat = new Date("03/07/2018 10:00 AM");
    console.log(dat.toISOString());
```

I took reference from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp)

Comment: `but it isn't working` what is not working?

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: @Zenoo: But isn't specified behavior.

Comment: @ user9287106 - You need to parse the date (on purpose), and then use `toISOString` on the result. **Every single variation of "how do I parse a date in JavaScript" has been asked and answered.** Do you research before posting. Search for previous answers. More on searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't get it, isn't his snippet's result exactly what he was asking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dat.toUTCString()` to get date as UTC string.

Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC